# generate a new variable based on the aging of another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, gdata

I have a dataset likes like below

```
ID. Invoice. Date of Invoice.  paid or not.  

1    1         10/31/2019       yes
1    1         10/31/2019       yes
1    2         11/30/2019       no
1    3         12/31/2019       no

2    1         09/30/2019       no
2    2         10/30/2019       no
2    3         11/30/2019       yes

3    1         7/31/2019        no
3    2         9/30/2019        yes
3    3         12/31/2019       no

4    1         7/31/2019        yes
4    2         9/30/2019        no
4    3         12/31/2019       yes
```

I would like to know whether the customers' willingness to pay. As long as a customer has paid a new invoice with an old invoice not paid, I will give him a good score. so for customer 1 and 3, I gave "good", customer 2 is a "bad" score.

so the final data will have one more column, with values of good and bad.

ID. Invoice. Date of Invoice.  paid or not.  Bad or good

```
1    1         10/31/2019       yes          bad
1    1         10/31/2019       yes          bad
1    2         11/30/2019       no           bad
1    3         12/31/2019       no           bad

2    1         09/30/2019       no           good
2    2         10/30/2019       no           good
2    3         11/30/2019       yes          good

3    1         7/31/2019        no           good
3    2         9/30/2019        yes          good
3    3         12/31/2019       no           good

4    1         7/31/2019        yes          good
4    2         9/30/2019        no           good
4    3         12/31/2019       yes          good
```

Comment: Yes good eye. XD I have edited them.

Comment: Thanks, rgarding the logic, how you are categorizing.  Not clear to me

Comment: Here are all customer's all invoices. As long as a new invoice is paid while an old one is still not, I will assume he is still willing to pay rather than ignore the invoices at all.

Comment: For 'ID', 3, the 'yes' is on 9/30/2019, while the next invoice is not paid

Answer (score 2):

Not clear about the logic.  May be, we can check for 'yes' in any of the rows except the first row after grouping  by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Date_of_Invoice = mdy(Date_of_Invoice)) %>% 
   arrange(ID, Date_of_Invoice) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(flag = c('bad', 'good')[1 + any(paid_or_not[-1] == "yes")])
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Invoice Date_of_Invoice paid_or_not flag 
#  <int>   <int> <date>          <chr>       <chr>
#1     1       1 2019-09-30      no          good 
#2     1       2 2019-10-30      no          good 
#3     1       3 2019-11-30      yes         good 
#4     2       1 2019-10-31      yes         bad  
#5     2       2 2019-11-30      no          bad  
#6     2       3 2019-12-31      no          bad  
#7     3       1 2019-07-31      no          good 
#8     3       2 2019-09-30      yes         good 
#9     3       3 2019-12-31      no          good
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Invoice = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Date_of_Invoice = c("09/30/2019", 
"10/30/2019", "11/30/2019", "10/31/2019", "11/30/2019", "12/31/2019", 
"7/31/2019", "9/30/2019", "12/31/2019"), paid_or_not = c("no", 
"no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: hum, if the customer's oldest invoice is paid, then the code does not work anymore.

Comment: @Yufang Not clear though.  If you can update your post with a new example, would be helpful

Comment: I add one more example. The customers are all having both paid and unpaid invoices.  If a customer has a paid invoice from Step and an unpaid invoice from August, I would assume this customer did not pay the august invoice because he thinks the amount is off or some other reasons. so I still rank him as a good customer.

Comment: @Yufang I guess you posted a new question.  Is that the upddate of this one

Comment: on the other hand, if a customer has paid the invoices from the beginning to August and has not paid for August to now. I suspend he will never pay again. so I rank him as bad customer. If a customer has a habit of not paying on time, so with Jan invoice paid, Feb invoice not paid, august invoice paid again. I would also think he is a good customer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Date of Invoice.` is ordered already, then here is a base R solution using `ave`

```
df$`good or band.` <- ave(df$`paid or not.`,df$ID., FUN = function(v) ifelse(which(v=="yes")==1,"bad","good"))
```

such that

```
> df
  ID. Invoice. Date of Invoice. paid or not. good or band.
1   1        1       09/30/2019           no          good
2   1        2       10/30/2019           no          good
3   1        3       11/30/2019          yes          good
4   2        1       10/31/2019          yes           bad
5   2        2       11/30/2019           no           bad
6   2        3       12/31/2019           no           bad
7   3        1        7/31/2019           no          good
8   3        2        9/30/2019          yes          good
9   3        3       12/31/2019           no          good
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ID. = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Invoice. = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), `Date of Invoice.` = c("09/30/2019", 
"10/30/2019", "11/30/2019", "10/31/2019", "11/30/2019", "12/31/2019", 
"7/31/2019", "9/30/2019", "12/31/2019"), `paid or not.` = c("no", 
"no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```