# Generate a new variable based on the time of another variable value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset likes like below

```
ID. Invoice. Date of Invoice.  paid or not.  

1    1         10/31/2019       yes
1    1         10/31/2019       yes
1    2         11/30/2019       no
1    3         12/31/2019       no

2    1         09/30/2019       no
2    2         10/30/2019       no
2    3         11/30/2019       yes

3    1         7/31/2019        no
3    2         9/30/2019        yes
3    3         12/31/2019       no
```

I would like to know whether the customers' willingness to pay. As long as a customer has paid a new invoice with an old invoice not paid, I will give him a good score. so for customer 2 and 3, I gave "good", customer 2 is a "bad" score.

so the final data will have one more column, with values of good and bad.

```
ID. Invoice. Date of Invoice.  paid or not.  Bad or good

1    1         10/31/2019       yes          bad
1    1         10/31/2019       yes          bad
1    2         11/30/2019       no           bad
1    3         12/31/2019       no           bad

2    1         09/30/2019       no           good
2    2         10/30/2019       no           good
2    3         11/30/2019       yes          good

3    1         7/31/2019        no           good
3    2         9/30/2019        yes          good
3    3         12/31/2019       no           good
```

Comment: How exactly does this differ from the question you [posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60121743/5325862) besides having a slightly smaller data sample?

Comment: Hi @camille, I just noticed that too. What's going on? Dear Yufang, if someone has answered your question in the previous post, please accept the answer. If there is a separate issue here, I hope I have addressed it somehow. Not good to have three versions of code swimming around, duplicating efforts.

Comment: Hi sorry about this, I posted it yesterday but the answer does not solve the problem.  so I added more details here in this post. apologies if it is duplicate. Should i delete another post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data:

```
df = structure(list(ID. = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), Invoice. = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Date.of.Invoice. = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 5L), .Label = c("09/30/2019", 
"10/30/2019", "10/31/2019", "11/30/2019", "12/31/2019", "7/31/2019", 
"9/30/2019"), class = "factor"), paid.or.not. = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

You can try something like this:

```
label_func = function(i){
if (all(i==2)) {
"good"
} else if (any(diff(i)>0)) {
"good"
} else{"bad"}
}

library(dplyr)
df$paid.or.not. = factor(df$paid.or.not.,levels=c("no","yes"))
df %>% group_by(ID.) %>% 
mutate(score=label_func(as.numeric(paid.or.not.)))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   ID. [3]
     ID. Invoice. Date.of.Invoice. paid.or.not. score
   <int>    <int> <fct>            <fct>        <chr>
 1     1        1 10/31/2019       yes          bad  
 2     1        1 10/31/2019       yes          bad  
 3     1        2 11/30/2019       no           bad  
 4     1        3 12/31/2019       no           bad  
 5     2        1 09/30/2019       no           good 
 6     2        2 10/30/2019       no           good 
 7     2        3 11/30/2019       yes          good 
 8     3        1 7/31/2019        no           good 
 9     3        2 9/30/2019        yes          good 
10     3        3 12/31/2019       no           good
```

Explanation on how it works. In your data frame, the column paid.or.not. is encoded as a factor (normally). In the code above, I enforced it, and setting "no" as the first and "yes" as second. If we do `as.numeric()` to this column:

```
df %>% mutate(score=as.numeric(paid.or.not.))
   ID. Invoice. Date.of.Invoice. paid.or.not. score
1    1        1       10/31/2019          yes     2
2    1        1       10/31/2019          yes     2
3    1        2       11/30/2019           no     1
4    1        3       12/31/2019           no     1
5    2        1       09/30/2019           no     1
6    2        2       10/30/2019           no     1
7    2        3       11/30/2019          yes     2
8    3        1        7/31/2019           no     1
9    3        2        9/30/2019          yes     2
10   3        3       12/31/2019           no     1
```

We can see that it gets 1 or 2. When there is a "yes" after "no", you would label it as good, that means their difference is +1.

We can look at it like this:

```
df %>% mutate(score=as.numeric(paid.or.not.)-lag(as.numeric(paid.or.not.)))

   ID. Invoice. Date.of.Invoice. paid.or.not. score
1    1        1       10/31/2019          yes    NA
2    1        1       10/31/2019          yes     0
3    1        2       11/30/2019           no    -1
4    1        3       12/31/2019           no     0
5    2        1       09/30/2019           no     0
6    2        2       10/30/2019           no     0
7    2        3       11/30/2019          yes     1
8    3        1        7/31/2019           no    -1
9    3        2        9/30/2019          yes     1
10   3        3       12/31/2019           no    -1
```

You can see those that you want to label "good" have at least a +1 while those "bad" have no "+1". One last exception is, if all are "yes" and all are "no":

```
test=data.frame(ID.=1:2,Invoice.=1,
Date.of.Invoice.="12/31/2019",paid.or.not.=c("yes","no"))
test$paid.or.not. = factor(test$paid.or.not.,levels=c("no","yes"))
test %>% group_by(ID.) %>% 
mutate(score=label_func(as.numeric(paid.or.not.)))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   ID. [2]
    ID. Invoice. Date.of.Invoice. paid.or.not. score
  <int>    <dbl> <fct>            <fct>        <chr>
1     1        1 12/31/2019       yes          good 
2     2        1 12/31/2019       no           bad
```

Comment: yes, if all are yes, I would put "good" to the customer. I am wondering if part of customers only has one invoice, either paid or not, will they be marked as NA?

Comment: If there's only one "yes", it should be "good". if there's only one "no", it will be "bad". I am asking because my dataset contains too many IDs and I cannot find one example to check whether the code is working in this way.

Comment: Ok, the code works like what you wanted actually. see above

Comment: Thank you so much, it is explained very clearly. one more question, how can I delete customers who only have paid invoices in the first place.

Comment: You have to find the IDs first. rmv_IDs = df %>% group_by(ID.) %>% summarise(yes=mean(paid.or.not.=="yes")) %>% filter(yes==1) %>% pull(ID.). Then you subset(df,! ID. %in% rmv_IDs)